# Getting error in Integration of Google plus with android in eclipse

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using google+ login for my application.
First time user is login. When user is logout and again same user try to login then I got,
`Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` is null.

How to solve this error.

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {        

    // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.
    // Update the user interface to reflect that the user is signed in.
    // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the
    // user.

    Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(null);
    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

    String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (currentUser == null) {
        Utils.signOutAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (isGooglePlusClicked) {
            isGooglePlusClicked = false;
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Google sign-in is not available for now. "
                            + "Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
        }
        return;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "g+ onConnected isSignInClicked currentUser=" + currentUser);
    BaseWebServiceRunner webServiceRunner = new BaseWebServiceRunner(this);

    Log.i(TAG, "g+ onConnected isGooglePlusClicked value=" + isGooglePlusClicked);

    if (isGooglePlusClicked) {
        isGooglePlusClicked = false;
        if (edit_username.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setFname(currentUser.getDisplayName());
            UserGoogle usergoogle = new UserGoogle();
            usergoogle.setAbout_me(currentUser.getAboutMe());
            usergoogle.setBirthdate(currentUser.getBirthday());
            switch (currentUser.getGender()) {
            case 1:
                usergoogle.setGender("FEMALE");
                user.setGender("FEMALE");
                break;
            case 0:
                usergoogle.setGender("MALE");
                user.setGender("MALE");
                break;
            default:
                usergoogle.setGender("OTHER");
                user.setGender("OTHER");
                break;
            }

            Image image = currentUser.getImage();
            if (image != null && image.hasUrl()) {
                // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want
                // by
                // replacing sz=X
                String actualUrl = image.getUrl();
                String url = actualUrl.substring(0, actualUrl.length() - 2)
                        + Prefs.SCALE_BITMAP_WIDTH;
                user.setPicture(url);
            }

            usergoogle.setLogin_name(email);
            user.setGoogle(usergoogle);
            user.setEmail(email);
            user.setUsername(email);
            user.setPassword("123456");
            user.setRegister_by(UserLoginType.Google.toString());

            user.setAddress1(SharedPreferenceConnector.readString(this, Prefs.ADDRESS_LINE_0, ""));
            user.setAddress2(SharedPreferenceConnector.readString(this, Prefs.ADDRESS_LINE_1, ""));
            user.setCity(SharedPreferenceConnector.readString(this, Prefs.CITY_NAME, ""));
            user.setState(SharedPreferenceConnector.readString(this, Prefs.STATE_NAME, ""));
            user.setCountry(SharedPreferenceConnector.readString(this, Prefs.COUNTRY_NAME, ""));

            //              user.setDevice_id(Utility.getDeviceId(this));

            UserRegistrationWS registrationWS = new UserRegistrationWS(
                    this, user, UserRegistrationType.NEW);
            UserRegistrationWS[] params = new UserRegistrationWS[1];
            params[0] = registrationWS;
            webServiceRunner.execute(params);
        }
    } else {
        Utils.signOutAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
    }
    gServicesSignInProg = STATE_DEFAULT;
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: without code how can someone help..?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(null);
```

with

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(this);
```